# Transfer iOS developer account to someone else?

Tags: ios, certificate

I have an iOS developer account.
I'm not gonna use it during the next two months and would like to transfer it to another developer (for this time).

not the actual access to the developper account, also not the possibility to upload apps to the appstore, but for him to create a developper account that lets him deploy his app during these two months to the devices.

Is this possible? how can I do that?

Comment: How Do I do that? I can't find such an option in the provisioning portal

Comment: You can't add someone to your team unless you've got a business account. The cost of the account is the same ($99), but you have to provide more documentation than you do for an individual account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an individual account, it's not possible unless you share your certificate and private key with the other developer. You need a business account if you want to have multiple developers on a development team.

Comment: is it possible to make a copy of my certificate that is valid only for two months?

Comment: No. (SO would like a more detailed response, but the answer is still no.)